# Easy DIY photo paper?

Tags: diy, pinhole-cameras

I have no film for my pinhole camara, and i can't buy any.

how can i take easy safe photos? I can't buy anything.
I WILL ACCEPT ANYTHING. EVEN LEAVES.

Comment: Why can't you buy any? Are you looking to actually make your own film, or are you looking for a list of all possible alternative photographic processes?

Comment: When you say "I can't buy anything" - does that mean you can't buy inexpensive material? some photographic sensitive paper? or even chemicals to make the photographic paper? Without some guidance... well, you could use [asphalt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliography), but I'm not sure that is what you are after. Could you please clarify the restrictions you have on options for storing the image?

Comment: I just became a teen, an I have no money

Comment: Can you afford to buy something that costs $7 for 15 sheets of paper? ([sun sensitive paper](http://www.stevespanglerscience.com/sun-sensitive-paper.html)).  If the answer is 'yes', then William's answer is correct.  If the answer is 'no', you are likely out of luck - even the simplest chemistry ([Ferric Ammonium Citrate](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/123827-REG/) and [Potassium Ferricyanide](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/123966-REG/)) costs some money (and will involve a bit of chemistry glassware too).

Answer (score 2):

You can buy blueprint paper [or make your own](http://chemistry.about.com/od/colorchemistryprojects/a/How-To-Make-Blueprint-Paper.htm). It's not going to be nearly as sensitive as film, so you'll need long exposures and/or a lot of light, but with patience you should be able to make a (blue) image with your camera. On the plus side, developing the image is very simple -- all you need is a dimly lit room and water.

Comment: Could you please replicate at least part of the article or include a brief? Remember links can break over time.

Comment: @Jahaziel Edited to make the link less important. I don't think it makes sense to repeat the directions here -- the recipe isn't really the point of this answer so much as the idea that you can use blueprint paper to record an image.